# Enriching a json with translate/lookup field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm trying to enrich a JSON file that I have with an extra field named "country" (I know there are probably some OOTB lookup already, but I'm trying to do this manually for other use cases.). I'm doing this with the help of the translate filter:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/Users/Downloads/logs/test1.json"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    codec => "json"
  }
}

filter {
  translate {
    field => "remote_addr"
    dictionary_path => "/Users/Downloads/logs/ip_list.json"
    refresh_interval => 3600
    destination => "country"
    fallback => "Unknown"
  }
}

output {
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

test1.json contains:
`{"remote_addr": "7.7.7.7", "ioc":"false"}`

and ip_list.json contains:
`{"ip": "7.7.7.7", "country":"sweden"}`

However, it always defaults back to "Unknown" where as it shouldn't, because the field is present in the dictionary_path?

I've tried different json files but the result is the same. I was expecting it to find the country field in the lookup/translate and add it to the main json file.

The stdout contains:

```
{
     "@timestamp" => 2023-12-10T13:20:00.384715Z,
            "log" => {
        "file" => {
            "path" => "/Users/Downloads/logs/test1.json"
        }
    },
        "country" => "Unknown",
           "host" => {
        "name" => "uxxx"
    },
            "ioc" => "false",
          "event" => {
        "original" => "{\"remote_addr\": \"7.7.7.7\", \"ioc\":\"false\"}"
    },
       "@version" => "1",
    "remote_addr" => "7.7.7.7"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The translate filter does a lookup of the source field in the JSON hash created from the dictionary. ip_list.json should contain

```
{"7.7.7.7": "sweden"}
```

The filter will not search the dictionary for keys that contain a matching value (i.e. to see if the value any "ip" key matches the source field).